# Change metric format in Google Data Studio

Tags: formatting, reporting, looker-studio

Is it possible in some way to transform a GDS graph metric into a more abbreviated value?

The issue is that it's very hard to read numbers in some graphs that require multiple series:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, the [25 Feb 2021 Update](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10331528#feb-25-2021) to Google Data Studio introduced **Compact Numbers** in charts, as well as **Decimal Precision**:

### Style Tab

```
Show Data Labels: Tick
Compact Numbers: Tick
Decimal Precision: 0
```

[Editable Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/02ad446f-fc87-4c84-88fa-02f71493ea24) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have made a little research and I'm sorry but it seems that **Google has not that feature yet** (or it may not will if you think in a button or just a click), due to others like you have requested to Google's team to offer them a solution with a question like yours that was made in 2019 and, I don't know why but, it is closed and neither Google's team or any other user has provided a solution for this issue. I left you the question's link just for good health:

https://support.google.com/datastudio/thread/10391657?hl=en&msgid=10391657

The only good news for you is that the **Scorecard Chart** it can convert to k's for thousands and M's for Millions using the feature "compact numbers" in the Style tab. I hope this it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Do you have to show data labels? I think it is more "clean" to just show the value when you hover over the bar, like in this [sample report](https://datastudio.google.com/u/0/org//reporting/0B_U5RNpwhcE6SF85TENURnc4UjA/page/1M/preview).

Comment: The problem is when ou need to show lots of graphs at the same time, it becomes tedious to hover over each bar one by one

Comment: There are two workarounds I can think of. 1) adding a new column to round the data (e.g. 163,904 to 164K) if you don't need the exact number.   2) Changing style to Horizontal Bar chart, then you can see the detailed value and they won't be overlapped.